# Access Fusion Table to show up in Map Using FusionTableMap API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, oauth, google-fusion-tables

I have created service account in google to access and upload data in the fusion table .I am able to authenticate using OAuth and push the data in fusion table of service account .But when i am trying to access the same table using tableid in the map i am not able to access the same .Table created are not showing up in my main account . I read some questions in stackoverflow they talked of giving permssion of FT (I am not able to do that even )

My code :

`/`

```
*
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Google Inc.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.google.api.services.samples.fusiontables.cmdline;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Permissions;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.Fusiontables;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.Fusiontables.Query.Sql;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.Fusiontables.Table.Delete;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.FusiontablesScopes;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.model.Column;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.model.Sqlresponse;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.model.Table;
import com.google.api.services.fusiontables.model.TableList;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * @author Christian Junk
 * 
 */
public class FusionTablesSample {

  /** E-mail address of the service account. */
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";




  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  private static Fusiontables fusiontables;

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorizeNew() throws Exception {

            // Build service account credential.
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)


        .setServiceAccountScopes(FusiontablesScopes.FUSIONTABLES)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
        .build();



       return credential;
  }

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorizeNewDrive() throws Exception {

      GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)


      .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
      .build();



     return credential;
  }






  /**
   * Insert a new permission.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to insert permission for.
   * @param value User or group e-mail address, domain name or {@code null}
                  "default" type.
   * @param type The value "user", "group", "domain" or "default".
   * @param role The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".
   * @return The inserted permission if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId,
      String value, String type, String role) {
    Permission newPermission = new Permission();

    newPermission.setValue(value);
    newPermission.setType(type);
    newPermission.setRole(role);
   try {
       System.out.println("service"+service.permissions());
      return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
      } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
   }
    return null;
  }

  /** Global Drive API client. */
  private static Drive drive;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      try {



//        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        // authorization
        Credential credential = authorizeNew();

        Credential credential1 = authorizeNewDrive();


        // set up global FusionTables instance
        fusiontables = new Fusiontables.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
            "FusionTable").build();


        // set up the global Drive instance
        drive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential1).setApplicationName(
            "FusionTable").build();


        System.out.println(drive.files().list());
        Permissions perms=drive.permissions();
        System.out.println(perms);



        // run commands
//        listTables();
        ArrayList<String> list=listTables("");

//       String tableId = createTable();
//        insertData(tableId);
        for(String tableid:list)
        {
            insertPermission(drive, tableid, "XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com","anyone","owner");
//          System.out.print(" permission for table id is  " + perms.list(tableid));
        showRows(tableid);
//        deleteTable(tableid);
        }
        listTables();
   //     deleteTable(tableId);
        // success!
        return;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
  }

  /**
   * @param tableId
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private static void showRows(String tableId) throws IOException {
    View.header("Start Showing Rows From Table");

    Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT Text,Number,Location,Address,Date FROM " + tableId);

    try {
     Sqlresponse response= sql.execute();
     System.out.println(  response.getColumns());
   System.out.println(  response.getRows());

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // For google-api-services-fusiontables-v1-rev1-1.7.2-beta this exception will always
      // been thrown.
      // Please see issue 545: JSON response could not be deserialized to Sqlresponse.class
      // http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=545
    }
    View.header("End Showing Rows From Table");
  }

  /** List tables for the authenticated user. */
  private static void listTables() throws IOException {
    View.header("Listing My Tables");

    // Fetch the table list
    Fusiontables.Table.List listTables = fusiontables.table().list();
    TableList tablelist = listTables.execute();

    if (tablelist.getItems() == null || tablelist.getItems().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No tables found!");
      return;
    }

    for (Table table : tablelist.getItems()) {
      View.show(table);
      View.separator();
    }
  }

  private static  ArrayList<String> listTables(String a) throws IOException {
    View.header("Listing My Tables");
    ArrayList<String> rt=new ArrayList<String>();
    // Fetch the table list
    Fusiontables.Table.List listTables = fusiontables.table().list();
    TableList tablelist = listTables.execute();

    if (tablelist.getItems() == null || tablelist.getItems().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No tables found!");
      return rt;
    }

    for (Table table : tablelist.getItems()) {
      rt.add(table.getTableId());
      View.show(table);
      View.separator();
    }
    return rt;
  }

  /** Create a table for the authenticated user. */
  private static String createTable() throws IOException {
    View.header("Create Sample Table");

    // Create a new table
    Table table = new Table();
    table.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    table.setIsExportable(true);

    table.setDescription("Sample Table");

    // Set columns for new table
    table.setColumns(Arrays.asList(new Column().setName("Text").setType("STRING"),
        new Column().setName("Number").setType("NUMBER"),
        new Column().setName("Location").setType("LOCATION"),
        new Column().setName("Address").setType("STRING"),
        new Column().setName("Date").setType("DATETIME")));

    // Adds a new column to the table.
    Fusiontables.Table.Insert t = fusiontables.table().insert(table);
    Table r = t.execute();

    View.show(r);

    return r.getTableId();
  }

  /** Inserts a row in the newly created table for the authenticated user. */
  private static void insertData(String tableId) throws IOException {
    Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("INSERT INTO " + tableId + " (Text,Number,Location,Address,Date) "
        + "VALUES (" + "'Google Inc', " + "1, " + "'22.816694,70.850418',  " + "'1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, "
        + "CA 94043, USA','" + new DateTime(new Date()) + "')");

    try {
      sql.execute();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // For google-api-services-fusiontables-v1-rev1-1.7.2-beta this exception will always
      // been thrown.
      // Please see issue 545: JSON response could not be deserialized to Sqlresponse.class
      // http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=545
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /** Deletes a table for the authenticated user. */
  private static void deleteTable(String tableId) throws IOException {
    View.header("Delete Sample Table");
    // Deletes a table
    Delete delete = fusiontables.table().delete(tableId);
    delete.execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is greek to me ...  What's the point of posting a generic FT Java module?
I don't see any Google Map code here or even the table id you're trying to access.
Use the UI to get to your table:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=[encoded table id]

In the Share settings, select either "Public on the web" or "Anyone with Link".  It should now be accessible via the Google Maps javascript API.

Comment: This is server side of the code which aggregates data and puts in the Fusion table . Our problem is we want to do it through program , we are able to insert data in table but not able to access the same table in my map code.

Answer (score 0):

> I read some questions in stackoverflow they talked of giving permssion of FT (I am not able to do that even )

Your code already contains that. Take a look at your insertPermission() method. The wonders of copy-paste... :)

According to Google Maps documentation, you can only display fusion tables on a map that are shared as "public" or "unlisted". 
Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesSetup

To achieve that set a permission on your table with role "reader" and type "anyone". For more info and a java sample see: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

Comment: My bad i was not able to make my question clear ,actually i am aware of insertPermission () method ,the problem around is even then i am getting not authorised error and i am not able to access the table created in my map application.

Comment: When i am trying to list the tables created using code drive.files.list() .its resulting in empty but show of table for method listTables() method

Comment: Probably you've created the fusion table with a **service account** and you want to inspect it on the Fusion Tables website with your **personal account**. You need to insert the permission via the same account you used to create the fusion table. After that, you (and everyone else) will be able to access(read) it.

Comment: Yeah i have tried  inserting permission using my service account credentials even then its failing do i need to take care of something else as well.